# How to get the stats of each game in livescore?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get the stats of each game on livescore and return all the stats of the whole game for a day at the same time.

```
driver.get('https://www.livescore.com/en/football/2022-12-01/')
time.sleep(2)
scroll_pause_time = 1 # You can set your own pause time. My laptop is a bit slow so I use 1 sec
screen_height = driver.execute_script("return window.screen.height;")   # get the screen height of the web
i = 0

while True:
    # scroll one screen height each time
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, {screen_height}*{i});".format(screen_height=screen_height, i=i))  
    i += 1
    time.sleep(scroll_pause_time)
    # update scroll height each time after scrolled, as the scroll height can change after we scrolled the page
    scroll_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight;") 
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
    divs = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'wk Ak')
    base_url = 'https://www.livescore.com'
    for p in divs:
        url = p.find('a', class_ = 'bi')
        urls = url['href']
        full_url= urljoin(base_url, urls)
        print(full_url)
        for a in full_url:
            a.click()
            
            
  
    
    # Break the loop when the height we need to scroll to is larger than the total scroll height
    if (screen_height) * i > scroll_height:
        break
```

I got stocked after getting the url, how to click on each of the url, get the information on each game and then do this for all the game and get the result

```
driver.get('https://www.livescore.com/en/football/2022-12-01/')
time.sleep(2)
scroll_pause_time = 1 # You can set your own pause time. My laptop is a bit slow so I use 1 sec
screen_height = driver.execute_script("return window.screen.height;")   # get the screen height of the web
i = 0

while True:
    # scroll one screen height each time
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, {screen_height}*{i});".format(screen_height=screen_height, i=i))  
    i += 1
    time.sleep(scroll_pause_time)
    # update scroll height each time after scrolled, as the scroll height can change after we scrolled the page
    scroll_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight;") 
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
    divs = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'wk Ak')
    base_url = 'https://www.livescore.com'
    for p in divs:
        url = p.find('a', class_ = 'bi')
        urls = url['href']
        full_url= urljoin(base_url, urls)
        print(full_url)
        for a in full_url:
            a.click()
            
            
  
    
    # Break the loop when the height we need to scroll to is larger than the total scroll height
    if (screen_height) * i > scroll_height:
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

Information in that page is being fed from an API endpoint (You can get that API endpoint if you inspect Dev tools - > Network Tab -> XHR calls).

Here is one way of getting that information:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}
url = 'https://prod-public-api.livescore.com/v1/api/app/date/soccer/20221201/0?MD=1'

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
df = pd.json_normalize(r.json()['Stages'], record_path=['Events'])
print(df)
```

Result in terminal:

```
    Eid Tr1 Tr2 Trh1    Trh2    Tr1OR   Tr2OR   T1  T2  Eps Esid    Epr Ecov    ErnInf  Ewt Et  Esd EO  Spid    Pid Pids.8  Pids.12 Media.32    Media.12
0   663917  2   4   0   1   2   4   [{'Nm': 'Costa Rica', 'ID': '6189', 'Img': 'enet/6705.png', 'NewsTag': '/team/costa-rica-2021020913320920836-3459/', 'Abr': 'CRI'}] [{'Nm': 'Germany', 'ID': '9016', 'Img': 'enet/8570.png', 'NewsTag': '/team/germany-2021020913320920836-1272/', 'Abr': 'GER'}]   FT  6   2   0   3   2.0 1   20221201190000  27050877    1   8   663917  SBTE_27791172   [{'ageRestricted': 'false', 'articleId': '2022120121025417238', 'type': 'RESULT'}]  [{'eventId': 'RTE Player', 'provider': 'ABELSON', 'allowedCountries': ['IE'], 'type': 'TV_CHANNEL'}, {'eventId': 'NPO 3', 'provider': 'ABELSON', 'allowedCountries': ['NL'], 'type': 'TV_CHANNEL'}, {'eventId': 'RTE 2', 'provider': 'ABELSON', 'allowedCountries': ['IE'], 'type': 'TV_CHANNEL'}, {'eventId': 'ITVX', 'provider': 'ABELSON', 'allowedCountries': ['GB'], 'type': 'TV_CHANNEL'}, {'eventId': 'ITV 4', 'provider': 'ABELSON', 'allowedCountries': ['GB'], 'type': 'TV_CHANNEL'}]
1   663916  2   1   0   1   2   1   [{'Nm': 'Japan', 'ID': '6326', 'Img': 'enet/6715.png', 'NewsTag': '/team/japan-2021020913320920836-1435/', 'Abr': 'JPN'}]   [{'Nm': 'Spain', 'ID': '9182', 'Img': 'enet/6720.png', 'NewsTag': '/team/spain-2021020913320920836-1770/', 'Abr': 'SPA'}]   FT  6   2   0   3   1.0 1   20221201190000  27050877    1   8   663916  SBTE_27791173   [{'ageRestricted': 'false', 'articleId': '2022120120574907933', 'type': 'RESULT'}]  [{'eventId': 'UTV', 'provider': 'ABELSON', 'allowedCountries': ['GB', 'IE'], 'type': 'TV_CHANNEL'}, {'eventId': 'STV', 'provider': 'ABELSON', 'allowedCountries': ['GB'], 'type': 'TV_CHANNEL'}, {'eventId': 'RTE Player', 'provider': 'ABELSON', 'allowedCountries': ['IE'], 'type': 'TV_CHANNEL'}, {'eventId': 'RTE News', 'provider': 'ABELSON', 'allowedCountries': ['IE'], 'type': 'TV_CHANNEL'}, {'eventId': 'NPO 1', 'provider': 'ABELSON', 'allowedCountries': ['NL'], 'type': 'TV_CHANNEL'}, {'eventId': 'ITV 1', 'provider': 'ABELSON', 'allowedCountries': ['GB'], 'type': 'TV_CHANNEL'}, {'eventId': 'ITVX', 'provider': 'ABELSON', 'allowedCountries': ['GB'], 'type': 'TV_CHANNEL'}]
2   663923  1   2   1   2   NaN NaN [{'Nm': 'Canada', 'ID': '335', 'Img': 'enet/5810.png', 'NewsTag': '/team/canada-2021020913320920836-2264/', 'Abr': 'CAN'}]  [{'Nm': 'Morocco', 'ID': '9111', 'Img': 'enet/6262.png', 'NewsTag': '/team/morocco-2021020913320920836-1540/', 'Abr': 'MOR'}]   FT  6   2   0   3   2.0 1   20221201150000  94159741    1   8   663923  SBTE_27791170   [{'ageRestricted': 'false', 'articleId': '2022120116574529109', 'type': 'RESULT'}]  [{'eventId': 'BBCi', 'provider': 'ABELSON', 'allowedCountries': ['GB'], 'type': 'TV_CHANNEL'}, {'eventId': 'RTE Player', 'provider': 'ABELSON', 'allowedCountries': ['IE'], 'type': 'TV_CHANNEL'}, {'eventId': 'RTE News', 'provider': 'ABELSON', 'allowedCountries': ['IE'], 'type': 'TV_CHANNEL'}, {'eventId': 'NPO 2', 'provider': 'ABELSON', 'allowedCountries': ['NL'], 'type': 'TV_CHANNEL'}, {'eventId': 'BBC Two', 'provider': 'ABELSON', 'allowedCountries': ['GB'], 'type': 'TV_CHANNEL'}]
3   663922  0   0   0   0   0   0   [{'Nm': 'Croatia', 'ID': '9138', 'Img': 'enet/10155.png', 'NewsTag': '/team/croatia-2021020913320920836-2342/', 'Abr': 'CRO'}]  [{'Nm': 'Belgium', 'ID': '9109', 'Img': 'enet/8263.png', 'NewsTag': '/team/belgium-2021020913320920836-2206/', 'Abr': 'BEL'}]   FT  6   2   0   3   0.0 1   20221201150000  94159741    1   8   663922  SBTE_27791171   [{'ageRestricted': 'false', 'articleId': '2022120116574414083', 'type': 'RESULT'}]  [{'eventId': 'BBCi', 'provider': 'ABELSON', 'allowedCountries': ['GB'], 'type': 'TV_CHANNEL'}, {'eventId': 'RTE Player', 'provider': 'ABELSON', 'allowedCountries': ['IE'], 'type': 'TV_CHANNEL'}, {'eventId': 'BBC One', 'provider': 'ABELSON', 'allowedCountries': ['GB'], 'type': 'TV_CHANNEL'}, {'eventId': 'NPO 1', 'provider': 'ABELSON', 'allowedCountries': ['NL'], 'type': 'TV_CHANNEL'}, {'eventId': 'RTE 2', 'provider': 'ABELSON', 'allowedCountries': ['IE'], 'type': 'TV_CHANNEL'}]
4   772739  2   0   2   0   0   0   [{'Nm': 'Chengdu Rongcheng', 'ID': '12402', 'Img': 'enet/737052.png', 'Abr': 'CHE'}]    [{'Nm': 'Guangzhou', 'ID': '6400', 'Img': 'enet/92646.png', 'Abr': 'GUA'}]  FT  6   2   0   28  1.0 1   20221201110000  1852285 1   8   772739  SBTE_28012822   NaN NaN
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
77  757915  1   1   0   1   1   1   [{'Nm': 'Steaua Bucuresti', 'ID': '181108', 'Img': 'enet/1277917.png', 'Abr': 'STE'}]   [{'Nm': 'FC Buzau', 'ID': '181106', 'Img': 'enet/1269098.png', 'Abr': 'FCB'}]   FT  6   2   0   16  0.0 1   20221201130000  1835277 1   8   757915  SBTE_28004131   NaN NaN
78  710531  0   0   0   0   0   0   [{'Nm': 'Olimpija Ljubljana', 'ID': '7807', 'Img': 'enet/7872.png', 'Abr': 'OLI'}]  [{'Nm': 'NK Celje', 'ID': '7877', 'Img': 'enet/4622.png', 'Abr': 'NKC'}]    FT  6   2   0   NaN 0.0 1   20221201170000  1851773 1   8   710531  SBTE_27988519   NaN [{'eventId': '2149301', 'provider': 'PERFORM', 'allowedCountries': ['NL'], 'type': 'LIVE_STREAMING'}]
79  787393  1   1   1   1   0   0   [{'Nm': 'Kinondoni MC', 'ID': '4219', 'Img': 'enet/1045551.png', 'Abr': 'KIN'}] [{'Nm': 'Mbeya City', 'ID': '4239', 'Img': 'enet/465620.png', 'Abr': 'MBE'}]    FT  6   2   0   15  0.0 1   20221201130000  1835277 1   8   787393  NaN NaN NaN
80  782216  2   2   1   1   2   2   [{'Nm': 'Zorya', 'ID': '6662', 'Img': 'enet/7770.png', 'Abr': 'ZOR'}]   [{'Nm': 'FC Kolos Kovalivka', 'ID': '6725', 'Img': 'enet/599924.png', 'Abr': 'FCK'}]    FT  6   2   0   7   0.0 1   20221201110000  27018109    1   8   782216  NaN NaN NaN
81  813097  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN [{'Nm': 'Chornomorets Odessa U19', 'ID': '191540', 'Abr': 'CHO'}]   [{'Nm': 'FC Kryvbas Kriviy Rih U19', 'ID': '231222', 'Abr': 'FCK'}] NS  1   0   2   7   NaN 1   20221201090000  1585158 1   8   813097  NaN NaN NaN
82 rows × 24 columns
```

​You can drill down further in that JSON object response, and filter the information you need. See [pandas json_normalize](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) for more details.